# Is it possible to do an Event registration 'on behalf of organization' - similar to how that can be done on Contribution pages?

Tags: civievent, invoice

Scenario: John Smith registers for Event - buys 10 tickets -> $5000 total; These monies end up on John's Contribution record (and risk being TaxReceipted at the $5000 - advantage[food, cost] level). These monies really belong on John's company record -> Solar Panels Inc. Is there a way to configure a CiviCRM Event page such that John has an option while registering for the Event to let us know that the monies should go onto Solar Panels Inc.?

Comment: You can do this with CiviCRM Entity Price Set Field, and a little custom code...but that would be used on the Drupal display of the Event page...Ping me on mattermost if you want to get the pointers.  I've just did a custom event form which allows "on behalf of" where a Head of Household can register other family members, the contribution going to the contact registered, not the contact of the user registering. Not sure how to do that with the CiviCRM event form

Comment: Thanks Mark - yeah - figured this would require a think outside the box.

Comment: what did you end up doing - we needed same and did the required in an extension

Comment: webform civicrm :-)!